# Dependency inject into Express route

Tags: node.js, express

I need to inject my `db` object into the `securityHandler` object, but I can't seem to work out how to do it.

In the `securityHandler.authenticate` method I want to have access to all: `db`, `request` and `response`.

I've tried this:

```
app.post('/api/login', securityHandler.authenticate(request, response, db) );
```

and

```
SecurityHandler.prototype.authenticate = function authenticate(request, response, db) {};
```

**EDIT:**

nane suggested passing the db object to the constructor of SecurityHandler:

```
var security = new SecurityHandler(db);
```

SecurityHandler itself looks like this:

```
function SecurityHandler(db) {
    console.log(db); // Defined
    this.db = db;
}

SecurityHandler.prototype.authenticate = function authenticate(request, response, next) {
    console.log(this.db); // Undefined
};
```

The db object now exists in the constructor method, but for some reason is unaccessible in the authenticate method.

Comment: `securityHandler` is an object that was create using `securityHandler = new SecurityHandler()`? And what is `db` (where is this defined/created)  it nothing standard in express routing.

Comment: Both were created by me, yes with the "new" keyword.

Comment: why not inject into the the `SecurityHandler` constructor `securityHandler = new SecurityHandler(db)`, or just require there ...

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9250851/do-i-need-dependency-injection-in-nodejs-or-how-to-deal-with

Answer (score 0):

`securityHandler.authenticate(request, response, db)` would immediately call `authenticate` as of that you would pass the result of the `authenticate` call as callback to `app.post('/api/login', /*...*/)`.

You would need to do it that way:

```
app.post('/api/login', function(request, response) {
   securityHandler.authenticate(request, response, db);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write a custom middleware in express.js and use it before route any request.

For more about custom middleware - you can refer -
[Express.js Middleware Demystified](https://blog.safaribooksonline.com/2014/03/10/express-js-middleware-demystified/)

Now in this middleware you can implement authentication related functionality which will fire before all request and you can manipulate code on basis of your request.url in the middleware itself.

Hope this will help you.
Thanks.